# SEO サイトURLは.htmlを抜くかindex.htmlにするか

Tags: nginx

自作CMSでブログを作っているんですが、URL部分はどのようにするのが、正しいでしょうか？

A

```
http://hoge.com/kijiurl/
/var/www/html/kijiurl/index.html
```

B

```
http://hoge.com/kijiurl
/var/www/html/kijiurl.html
```

BはNginx側で末尾.htmlを省きます。

現在はAにしているのですが、末尾スラッシュ無しにアクセスするとスラッシュ有りにリダイレクトして、その分100msほど無駄にします。↓

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`<a>`リンクにスラッシュ有りで移動するといちいちリダイレクトせずに済みます。↓

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Bの場合末尾スラッシュ有りのアクセスにはどう対応していますか？ それとも、現状は全て末尾スラッシュ無しのアクセスなのでしょうか。

Comment: Bの場合末尾スラッシュ有りは404になります.
既にある内部リンクは末尾スラッシュなしになっています。アクセスすると301 Moved Permanentlyリダイレクトしスラッシュが付与されます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「正しい」かは分かりませんが、自分ならこうしたいです。

- Aの方法でホスティングし続ける
- これから作られる被リンクは正しいURL(末尾スラッシュ有り)になるようにする
- 既存のリンクを正しいURLに変更する事も検討する

質問のケースに当てはまる状況というのはあまり無いと思いますが、以下の点が多少は参考になるでしょうか。

#### SEO

- [URL末尾の`/`はページランクに影響しない](http://googlewebmastercentral-ja.blogspot.jp/2010/11/url.html)
  最近ではURLにファイルの拡張子めいた物があっても問題ないという話も出ていました。
  こういう事はどうでもいいのでしょう。
- [301 での転送は影響する](https://www.suzukikenichi.com/blog/what-percentage-of-pagerank-is-lost-through-a-301-redirect/)
  上記インタビューは貯めたページランクが移転先にどれくらい引き継がれるかという話のようで、質問のケースとはちょっと違いますが、被リンクは正しいURLで集めた方がいいとは推測します。
- [ページの読み込み速度は影響する](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html)
  質問のケースのようにリダイレクトが発生する被リンクしかないコンテンツが「遅い」と判断されるかは分かりません。
  細かい事を考えると、Aの方が速くしやすいかな、とは思います。

#### ファイルとURLを対応させる（静的ホスティング）一般的なやり方

静的なコンテンツがメインであれば一般的な方法に従っておくという考え方もあります。
別のソフトウェア、サービスで動かす時に楽です。
`index.html`のような決った名前のファイルを末尾スラッシュのURLに結び付けるのが一般的です(Aの方法)。
例えば[`S3`でもそう](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html)です。